# Can't find solution to upgrade Stripe SDK

Tags: android, flutter, stripe-payments, google-play-services

[image]

I am trying to publish my application to play store but I get following error.
I am new to flutter and I don't know where to upgrade this SDK as I have not included it in my build.gradle or pubspec.yaml

> Error
> SDK Stripe Android SDK (com.stripe:stripe-android), 10.4.6 facilitates the transmission or collection of personal and sensitive information. Such behavior must comply with Google Play's Prominent Disclosure & Consent Requirements and applicable privacy policy requirements as described in the User Data policy. You can't publish this release due to this policy issue.
> To be allowed to publish, you may consider upgrading to 16.9.0, which the SDK provider has recommended for use instead. Please consult the SDK provider for further information.

Comment: Please paste the text of the error, not screenshots. That way, if someone in the future has the same error, they can find the solution. It will also increase the chances that someone will take the time to help you.

Comment: That's very odd, did you try a project-wide search for the "stripe" keyword ?

Comment: @Pallav Nagar I'm also facing same issue 2-3 projects. did you got solution?

Answer (score 6):

I had exactly the same error in the Google Play console. It was asking to upgrade sdk to 16.9.0 meanwhile that version was aborting.
The only solution which worked in my case was upgrading SDK to 10.5.0.

```
    implementation 'com.stripe:stripe-android:10.5.0'
```

It is a hot fix version which resolves the Google Play compliance issues.
Hope this will hep you.

Answer (score 2):

There's a simple fix to this:

1. Install [patch-package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package) & add it to your `post-install` script
2. Go to `node_modules/tipsi-stripe/android/build.gradle` and change `implementation 'com.stripe:stripe-android:10.4.6'` to `implementation 'com.stripe:stripe-android:10.5.0'`
3. Re-sync gradle
4. Apply patch: `yarn patch-package tipsi-stripe`
5. Done!

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone uses React Native, this helped me to get it updated and launched in Google Play Store: https://gitmemory.com/issue/tipsi/tipsi-stripe/785/861289460

Answer (score 0):

The error was caused due to the use of stripe-payment : 1.0.9  in pubspec.yaml and simply upgrading it didn't actually solve the problem. I had to open build.gradle in a new window as android project and in the file build.gradle, implementing suggested 16.9.0 and whenever we change the build.gradle it starts re-indexing and afterwards the issue was resolved.